# How do I refill a CD887A inkjet cartridge?

Tags: inkjet-printer, cartridge

(Question was edited to reflect: [Why is a question on Inkjet refill Off Topic for Superuser?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/10889/why-is-a-question-on-inkjet-refill-off-topic-for-superuser))

I have an HP Inkjet printer with a CD887A[image: CD887A] cartridge. How do i refill it? Here's a photo:

Comment: wait. Are you mixing your own inks?

Comment: Single use only is on there for medical legal reasons. So long as you rinse it out after there is no reason you can't reuse them. I reuse mine all the time for messing with my plotter.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek yeah want to but finding it hard to source the chemicals. Some inkjet *Glycerol* recipes are published by *Paul Roark's* lab you can check them out here (open source inks):https://www.inksupply.com/roarkslab.cfm

Comment: Refilling some cartridges is more complicated than squirting ink in a hole.   The best advice is probably to buy a refill kit for your cartridge and follow that kit's instructions, at least the first time.  That said, I couldn't find any refill kits for this cartridge, which may mean that the embedded chip makes the cartridge unusable at a predetermined point, so refilling is fruitless.  Creating your own ink would be off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

I've done this before. Typically refilling syringes are *huge*, and have the pointy bit of the needle reversed so its flat tipped and you can't stab yourself with it.. My local ink dealer tends to supply both squeeze bottles and syringes on request. 'Single' use syringes are just plastic, and should be fine, though [true single use syringes for medical use are just coming out on the market](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-31550817).

Typically there's a re-filling hole *under* the label somewhere. Remove the label (carefully) and probe to see where the needle can go in all the way. Withdraw the needle to check - unless its bone dry, you will see *some* ink.

Reinsert the needle *Saturate* the sponge until ink just starts to flow out, then replace the label or tape over the hole if it was covered. Don't bother flushing out the old ink. There's no real point. I've never done it over the *years* I've refilled ink on my printers.

As for whether its the right ink? It depends. My dealer just sells it by brand.

At the end of the day though, get some ink, see if you're happy with it, and if you are, just stick to the same maker. Unless you happen to have a gas chromatograph...